# Flow Auto Layout

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-support

Our team recently had a Flow Case with Salesforce rejected because the Flow was using Auto Layout and Auto Layout is still in Beta.
Has anyone else had this happen and does Auto Layout make a Flow Potentially less stable? From looking at the XML of the Flow Auto Layout just seems to change the X,Y positions of the nodes but is more happening under the hood that we can't see?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have Premier support?  I suppose you could create a different version of the flow, turn off auto-layout, and reopen your case for that version.

Comment: Hi David, Yes we have Premier Support and that is what we did but it made us ask more questions about our use of Auto Layout for our other Flows. Could this be an issue if Salesforce is claiming that this is a reason to close this case?